# Hiding a grouped column in a SSRS report and when it’s exported to Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a SSRS report that has multiple row and 2 column groupings and when I added an additional column within 1 of the column groupings and it’s using an expression to calculate the sum of a records based on a condition. I am getting the right record however I’m hiding this new column and referencing the results in a different new column outside the grouping. When I display the report it doesn’t show but when I exported the report to excel it adds that hidden column 5 times because the condition is for sectionid = 5 and there are 5 sections in the column grouped. I’ve tried global references where IFF equal to excel open or EXCEL and it doesn’t hide the grouped column in excel. This report is within a matrix and was an existing report that I had to modify with a new columns based on a calculation. What other way can I ensure that the new grouped column can stay hidden even when exported to Excel?

I’ve tried using a IIF statement using global!renderformat.name = “EXCELOPENXLM” or “EXCEL” as well as modifying the visibility of the column to hide which works great when viewing the report it’s hidden but when it’s exported to Excel that grouped column is visible.I wanted that hidden column to stay hidden in both the report and excel export of the report.

Comment: have you tried setting the visibility hidden expression to this? =iif(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive, False, True)

Comment: I tried that when I run the report with a date parameter it says the matrix contains a error ‘Object variable or with block variable not set’.

Comment: That sounds like it's a different problem.. does the error go away if you take away the visibility expression?

Comment: Yes it does I did find that the new column I added is using the parent of a grouped column and the duplicate maybe a result of the child group that is causing the extra column 5 times based on each section in the parent group, it’s still odd why it doesn’t show in the SSRS report but when imported to excel it shows those extra columns